# Background image (movieclip) final render appears flipped

Tags: rendering, movie-clip-editor

my background movie-clip final render appears flipped. I have checked whether the camera is mirrored or in the background image options if the 'flip horizon' is checked - I've tried to render with the 'vertical flip' option checked but still the final result is the same, a horizon flipped. The video appears on the correct horizon on the 3d viewer, even on the render result preview. When i choose render active scene, blender renders out the background video flipped.  [image: I am attaching a screen shot of the composer's view]

Please, some one help me out, thank you.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the full compositing tree? If you disable compositing does the image appear normal?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to the people that replied.

OK, so the issue was that i had an object made linked to my video, when I created it i had flipped the horizon. I worked on some other objects, worked on camera tracking as well(in other words forgot about that object). When I remembered I had this object i hide it and flipped the backdrop image to its original horizon. So, when I was rendering the hide element was showing.

Yay!!

Answer (score -2):

In compositing, Shift+A -> Distort -> Flip; It reflects the image over the desired axis. Hope this helps...

[image]

Comment: I don't think they're trying to flip the whole image, just the background movie clip.

Comment: yes, the only thing flipping was the movie-clip. I figured it out last night. I am posting the answer.

Comment: yes, you can flip them separately! the flip node only effects what you plug in!